# Increase the mouse pointer size in a screen video recording after it was recorded and saved as an MP4 file

Tags: video, video-editing, accessibility, video-recording

I have the video file of a screen recording. I am looking for a program that can increase the mouse pointer size. The video is already recorded as a MP4 file.

Any operating system, browser, price or license is fine.